# How do I turn off text antialiasing in this Java function?

Tags: java, antialiasing

Basically I would like to turn off antialias in the following:

```
public BufferedImage createText(String text) {

    //create image
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(95, 20, 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    //set background
    graphics.setColor(Color.white);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 95, 20);

    //draw text
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);

    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics.setFont(new Font("volter", Font.PLAIN, 9));
    graphics.drawString(text, 0, 10);

    return image;
}
```

but it's not working, here is something this function generates:

[image]

I just want black and white to be used, nothing else so it's important I get antialias disabled!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                          RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
```